# Python inline of XML or ASCII string/template?

Tags: python

I am generating complex XML files through Python scripts that require a bunch of conditional statements (example http://repository.azgs.az.gov/uri_gin/azgs/dlio/536/iso19139.xml). I am working with multiple XML or ASCII metadata standards that often have poor schema or are quite vague.

In PHP, I just wrote out the XML and inserted PHP snippets where needed. Is there an easy way to do that in Python? I am trying to avoid having to escape all that XML. The inline method is also very helpful for tweaking the template without much rewrite.

I have looked a bit into Python templeting solutions but they appeared either too static or were overkill. Moving the whole XML into an XML object is a lot of work at a cost of flexibility when changing the XML or ASCII template.

Thanks for the newbie support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wgrunberg,

I use Python's built-in string.Template class like so:

```
from string import Template
the_template = Template("<div id='$section_id'>First name: $first</div>")
print the_template.substitute(section_id="anID", first="Sarah")
```

The output of the above is:

```
<div id='anID'>First name: Sarah</div>
```

In the above example I showed an XML template, but any "template" that you can describe as a string would work.

To do conditionals you can do something like:

```
print the_template.substitute(section_id="theID", first="Sarah" if 0==0 else "John")
```

If your conditionals are complex, instead of expressing them inline as above, consider breaking them out into closures/functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try any modern non-XML-based Python templating engine, e.g. [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) or [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/). They are  fairly easy to integrate into your project, and then you will be able to write things such as:

```
<sometag>
%if a > b:
   <anothertag />
%endif
</sometag>
```

You can also use [inline python](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/syntax.html#syntax_python), including assignments.

Answer (score 1):

@Gintautas' suggestion of using a good template engine would also be my first choice (especially Mako, whose "templating language" is basically Python plus some markup;-).

However, alternatives many people prefer to build XML files include writing them from the DOM, e.g. using (to stick with something in the standard library) [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or (a third-party package, but zero trouble to install and very popular) [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (by all means stick with its 3.0.x release unless you're using Python 3!), specifically the `BeautifulStoneSoup` class (the `BeautifulSoup` class is for processing HTML, the stone one for XML).

Answer (score 0):

Going for a template is the sensible thing to do. Using the build-in string template over external libraries would be my preferred method because I need to be able to pass on the Python ETL scripts easily to other people. However, I could get away with using templates by putting the XML string inside single quotes and using multi-line strings. Following is an example of this crude method.

```
    for row in metadata_dictionary:
        iso_xml = ''
        iso_xml += ' *** a bunch of XML *** '
        iso_xml += '\
<gmd:contact> \n\
    <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty> \n'
        if row['MetadataContactName']:
            iso_xml += '\
      <gmd:individualName> \n\
        <gco:CharacterString>'+row['MetadataContactName'].lower().strip()+'</gco:CharacterString> \n\
      </gmd:individualName> \n'
        if row['MetadataContactOrganisation']:
            iso_xml += '\
      <gmd:organisationName> \n\
        <gco:CharacterString>'+row['MetadataContactOrganisation'].lower().strip()+'</gco:CharacterString> \n\
      </gmd:organisationName> \n'
        iso_xml += ' *** more XML *** '
```